# Python: regular expression to find all function calls in a file but not function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am parsing a `C` code file using Python and I need to find all function calls, but not function definitions. For example:

```
txt = "foo(param1, bar1(foobar()), param2, !bar2(param3));"
```

should give me something like `foo, bar1, foobar, bar2`.

The regex I am using is `"\w+\("` :

```
import re
x = re.findall("\w+\(", txt)
```

but then it will also match function definition like this:

```
text = "void foo(int param) {"
```

How do I modify my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get away with using a negative lookahead in the matching pattern which asserts that no `{` appears in the input line:

```
txt = "foo(param1, bar1(foobar()), param2, !bar2(param3));"
matches = re.findall(r'(?!.*\{)\b\w+(?=\()', txt)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['foo', 'bar1', 'foobar', 'bar2']
```

But your second input has no matches:

```
txt = "void foo(int param) {"
matches = re.findall(r'(?!.*\{)\b\w+(?=\()', txt)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[]
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying to decode your regex :) I don't get why this group `(?!.*\{)` stays in front but not behind.

Comment: @hydradon The negative lookahead `(?!.*\{)` says to, from the very beginning of the string, assert that `{` does not occur _anywhere_ later in the string (i.e. from start to end).  We don't want to put this assertion later, because then it might admit some false positives.